# CSS - two column list spacing

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list that looks like this

```
--------------------
|        |         |
|   1    |    2    |
|        |         |
|   3    |    4    |
|        |         |
|   5    |    6    |
|        |         |
--------------------
```

(it's a simple `<ul>` with `<li>`'s)

the container of this list, let's call it `div.wrap` has a fixed width like 400 pixels, and the list items are floated to left with `50%` width.

How can I add a 10 pixel spacing between the left and right list items, without screwing up the layout?
Note that I have no control over the HTML from within the list, so I can't add any classes to these list items :(

I tried with `margin-right: 10px` on the `<li>`'s and `margin-right: -10px` on the `<ul>` but that doesn't work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[An example with margin-right](http://jsfiddle.net/YBy2K/1/).

**edit**
If you want to hide second margin, you can make `ul` a little bit bigger than its wrap and hide overflow:
http://jsfiddle.net/YBy2K/3/

Not terribly elegant, but simple enough.

Comment: yes, but that adds margin to the 2nd column too. that's why I'm trying to avoid :)

Comment: also li item width must be in percentages, because the container width can be altered, even if it's fixed.